# Internet Explorer Mobile 7.0 with Cookies from Java

Tags: java, internet-explorer, jsp, cookies

I have a webapplication based on jsp with Tomcat 6, and using cookies.

As client i use the HTC Mozart, IE Mobile 7.0 and it refuses my cookies, while having accept cookies enabled in options. I am creating the cookies as follows (javax.servlet.http.Cookie):

```java
Cookie tmpCookie = new Cookie("cookiename", "cookievalue");
tmpCookie.setPath("/");
tmpCookie.setMaxAge(365 * 24 * 60 * 60);

if (tmpCookie != null) {
    response.addCookie(tmpCookie);
}
```

It's working on almost all browsers, mobile and desktop, except the ie mobiles. Had no chance to test it on IEMobile9.0 yet. I could imagine that it has some troubles with the "/" path or something. Could you help me out?

Comment: why do you check if tmpCookie is not null if you just created it?